# Is there a way to group push notifications for different channels on getStream io

Tags: push-notification, getstream-io, getstream-chat, thread-id

Hi there problem solvers :)

I am using firebase as a push notification provider, I am trying to group push notifications for different channels and it is not working, I don't know if its the problem on the apn template on getstream dashboard, app is build using react native.

This is the apn template I am using on getstream dashboard on push notification page

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert": {
            "title": "{{ sender.name }} in {{ channel.name }}",
            "body": "{{ truncate message.text 2000 }}"
        },
        "mutable-content": 1,
        "category": "stream.chat",
        "thread-id": "{{ channel.cid }}"
    },
    "stream": {
        "sender": "stream.chat",
        "type": "message.new",
        "version": "v2",
        "id": "{{ message.id }}",
        "cid": "{{ channel.cid }}"
    }
}
```